# I am using facebook ios sdk 3.0 for logging into my app fb login working but not connecting to the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

this is the code i have used for the Facebook login for my app.i just followed this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/)

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (state)
{
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        if (!error) {
            // We have a valid session
            NSLog(@"User session found");
        }
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
 object:session];

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Comment: What screen do you see after filling the facebook page and pressing accept? or where exactly does it go to?

Comment: post code and then we can help you

Comment: this is the code i have used.i have entered all the other things         - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");
            }
            break;

Answer (score 0):

You have to call openSessionWithAllowLoginUI.